# Subquery returned more than 1 rows inside case statement

Tags: sql

I have been working on a query whereby in a subquery I am selecting the column `Cust_Status` under certain conditions.

```
select distinct 
    C.Cust_Code [Cust #],
    C.Cust_Start_Date [Start Date],
    C.Cust_End_date [End Date],
    (select 
         Cust_Status = (case  
                           when cast(CUST_UPDATE_DATE_LT as DATE) = cast('2017-01-23 00:00:00' as Date)
                              then 'V' 
                           when cast(CUST_UPDATE_DATE_LT as DATE) = cast('2017-01-22 00:00:00' as Date) 
                              then 'I'  
                        end)  
     from tblCustomers) [Cust Status],
    M.Machine_ID,
    M.Machine_Location
from 
    tblCustomers C   
inner join 
    tblMachine M on C.Cust_Mach_Pkey = M.Pkey
```

When I run this query I get an error

> subquery returned more than 1 value error.

When I remove the subquery inside case, it's fine. But I am sure there is only 1 record present for both date conditions. So not sure how my subquery returning more than 1 values. Please enlighten me.

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Provide sample data and desired results.  (3) Explain the logic you are trying to implement.

Comment: @Gordon: It makes little sense to post a 3-point question asking for additional details and then post an answer that negates the need or incentive to provide them.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? The code shown is invalid (standard) SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you just want to compare the latest date.  If so, there are much simpler ways:

```
select C.Cust_Code as [Cust #], C.Cust_Start_Date as [Start Date],
       C.Cust_End_date as [End Date],
       (case when max(cast(CUST_UPDATE_DATE_LT as DATE)) = '2017-01-23'
             then 'V'
             when max(cast(CUST_UPDATE_DATE_LT as DATE)) = '2017-01-22'
             then 'I'
        end) as Cust_status 
      M.Machine_ID,
      M.Machine_Location
from tblCustomers C inner join
     tblMachine M
     on C.Cust_Mach_Pkey = M.Pkey
group by C.Cust_Code, C.Cust_Start_Date, C.Cust_End_date,
         M.Machine_ID, M.Machine_Location
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i'm looking for an answer for if my subquery in selet statement returns more than 1 row, what can be the solution? For example select C.Cust_Code as [Cust #], C.Cust_Start_Date as [Start Date],
       C.Cust_End_date as [End Date],
       (case when max(cast(CUST_UPDATE_DATE_LT as DATE)) = '2017-01-23'
             then 'V'
             when max(cast(CUST_UPDATE_DATE_LT as DATE)) = '2017-01-22'
             then 'I'
        end) as Cust_status from tblCustomers.
How can avoid this subquery returned more than 1 value error.In select statement i cant use IN